# The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

Tags: php, symfony

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
     $helper = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

   return $this->render(
       'frontend/authenticate/login.html.twig',
       array(
           'last_username' => $helper->getLastUsername(),
           'error'         => $helper->getLastAuthenticationError(),
       )
   );
}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="security_login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction()
{

}
```

Comment: What's your question? The error is very clear and self explaining.

Comment: i am using two authentication like admin and users...admin authentication working properly...but when we login via user showing this error ...help me

Answer (score 0):

You should not provide an explicit action for the check_path part of the firewall definition.

Just point the `check_path`property of your firewall to the login action as shown in:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

> 1. Create the Correct Routes
>
>    > First, be sure that you've defined the /login route correctly and that it corresponds to the login_path and check_path config values. A misconfiguration here can mean that you're redirected to a 404 page instead of the login page, or that submitting the login form does nothing (you just see the login form over and over again).

Comment: Yep.  The actual login_check processor is actually a security listener.  Invisible to the the user program.

Comment: yep but i am using two authenticate controller like admin and user login ..user login controller only having this error...